# How to diagonalize a matrix with two eigenvalues that are the same and one eigenvalue that corresponds to two eigenvectors?

Tags: linear-algebra

I am not sure how to better word my question but basically I have this matrix:

$$
A:=\begin{pmatrix}
3 & -2 & 0\\
-2 & 3 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 5
\end{pmatrix}$$

And I ended up with Eigenvalues $= 5,5,1$. And when I solved for the eigenvectors, I got two eigen vectors for 1 and obviously the same one for the two eigenvalues that equal $5$.
For the eigenvalue=1. I got these two eigenvectors:

Eigenvector for $1$

$$\begin{pmatrix}
1\\
1\\
0 
\end{pmatrix}$$
$$\begin{pmatrix}
0\\
0\\
1 
\end{pmatrix}$$
And for $5$, I got this eigenvector:

$$\begin{pmatrix}
-1\\
1\\
0 
\end{pmatrix}$$

So how would I go about in creating matrix $P$ that corresponds to $A= PDP^{-1}$
Where P's vectors are the eigenvectors of the eigenvalues and $D$ is a diagonal matrix with the eigenvalues as the diagonal entries corresponding to the matrix $P$ eigenvectors arrangement.

How would $P$ look Like? Would I put the two eigenvectors first and then third eigenvector? Would that be an issue?

Comment: If you [edit] the question to show us the mathematics (not images) and your work we may be able to help you find your error. Use mathjax: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: If you got two eigenvectors for $1$ then you did it wrong; there should be no more than one linearly independent eigenvector for $1$ if the algebraic multiplicity is $1$. It is also possible for the matrix to not be diagonalizable, is the geometric multiplicity of $5$ is equal to $1$.

Comment: (0,0,1) is not an eigenvector for 1, it belongs to 5.

Comment: @Shiva: Putting the pictures in instead of the links may be marginally better, but [you still should not use images to convey information not otherwise present in the post](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/34123/742). They are not searchable, they are not accessible, and may display badly for some users.

Comment: @EthanBolker Hello! Is this edit better?

Comment: @Noname It is slightly better, but it's not what Ethan was referring to. It's not acceptable to use pictures instead of formatting your mathematics, matrices included. If you follow [the first answer in Ethan's link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5023) you'll find information about how to format matrices on this site.